# Unique url for pagination pages in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, pagination

I need unique url for pages of pagination.

When I click to number of page in pagination - url is changed, like *.../album/1/page/(number of choosen page)* - and it is ok, but when I try to copy my url and paste it like *(.../album/1/page/2)*, my app still load first page.

I need opportunity to load any pages from url.

This is my route for this moment:

```
<Route path="album/:id" component={AlbumsShow}>
    <Route path="page/:newPage" component={AlbumsShow} />
</Route>
```

And this is component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Pager from 'react-pager';
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';

class AlbumsShow extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.renderImage = this.renderImage.bind(this);
        this.handlePageChanged = this.handlePageChanged.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            total:       3,
            current:     0,
            visiblePage: 2,
        };
    }

    handlePageChanged(newPage) {
        this.setState({ current : newPage });
        browserHistory.push({
                pathname: (newPage+1),
            });
    }

    renderImage() {
        const imgs = this.props.images.length > 10 ?
              this.props.images.slice(this.state.current * 10, (this.state.current + 1) * 10) :
              this.props.images;
                return imgs.map((image, page) => (
                  <li className="image_list" key={image.id}>
                    <img className="image_list_img" alt="item" src={image.img} />
                  </li>
        ));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
              <ul>
                {this.renderImage()}
              </ul>

              {this.props.images.length > 10 ?

                <Pager
                  total={this.state.total}
                  current={this.state.current}
                  visiblePages={this.state.visiblePage}
                  titles={{ first: 'First page', last: 'Last page' }}
                  onPageChanged={this.handlePageChanged} 
                /> : null
              }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    const currentAlbumId = parseInt(ownProps.params.id, 10);

    return {
        images: state.main.albums.filter(album => album.id === currentAlbumId)[0].images,
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AlbumsShow);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the page number from the routing props, that is `:newPage` and map it in `mapStateToProps` as `pageNumber` (optionally).

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  const currentAlbumId = parseInt(ownProps.params.id, 10);
  const pageNumber = parseInt(ownProps.params.newPage, 10);

  return {
      pageNumber,
      images: state.main.albums.filter(album => album.id === currentAlbumId)[0].images,
  };
}
```

Then, instead of storing page number in the component's state, consume it as a prop.

```
<Pager current={this.props.pageNumber} ... />
```

When handling transition to the next page, just notify your router, don't store the state on your own. Your component will be re-rendered with the new pageNumber value.

```
handlePageChanged(newPage) {
    const { id } = this.props.params
    const { pageNumber } = this.props

    const target = `/albums/${id}/page/${pageNumber + 1}`

    browserHistory.push({
        pathname: target,
    });
}
```

All the way down, change occurrences of `this.state.current` to `this.props.pageNumber` and you are good to go.

The URL now becomes the [single source of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth).

---

Note: you can change routing parameters to better match their meaning:

```
<Route path="album/:albumId" component={AlbumsShow}>
    <Route path="page/:pageIndex" component={AlbumsShow} />
</Route>
```

After that you just consume those ids without mapping:

```
const { albumId, pageIndex } = this.props.params
```

Comment: When I changed current like you suggest `current={this.props.pageNumber}`
- my numbers in pagination are dissappear.

Comment: Have you passed current pageNumber in the `mapStateToProps` or another place? Check if it's defined or assign it to the default value: 
`const pageNumber = ownProps.params.newPage || 1`. If that won't work please show me the code after changes.

Comment: Instead of using renamed page number you may use your raw routing prop `newPage` as `this.props.params.newPage`. The code will then look like this: `current={this.props.params.newPage}`. Remember to change all occurrences in your code to account for this change.

Comment: Unfourtunately, it doesn't work. Can you add me to chat please?
I want to understand it to the end.

Comment: Don't know how to chat here yet, but I have created [a fiddle - take a look how the code might look like](https://jsfiddle.net/qfr61bto/).

Comment: You may try [joining the room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145108/reactjs) - I will be there for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You could check for the `page` param inside `componentWillReceiveProps` and set that as the `current` state, which is then updates the `Pager` component.

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  const { newPage } = newProps.params;
  if (newPage !== this.state.current) {
    this.setState({ current: page });
  }
}
```

Comment: This may potentially lead to an infinite loop. I think it would be important to have a flag that checks that the current param is not the same as before and only re-render when the param is new.

Comment: @promisified Yeah thanks, forgot to complete the `if` statement there!